# JPA Join Prints to many Results

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, jpa

I have four tables describing the Database:
Lecturer

````
@Entity
@Table(name = "LECTURER")

public class Lecturer
{
    private static final long            serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)  
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "NOBEL_PRICE_YEAR")
    private int nobel_price_year;
}```
````

Enrollment (Using Lecture and Student)

```
@Entity
@IdClass(EnrollmentId.class)
@Data
public class Enrollment
{
   @Id
   @JoinColumn(name = "lecture_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
   @ManyToOne
   private Lecture lecture;


   @Id
   @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
   @ManyToOne
   private Student student;

   @Id
   private int year;

   @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1)")
   private boolean exam_taken;
   @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1)")
   private boolean exam_passed;
}
```

With ID Class since Composite Primary Key

```
public class EnrollmentId implements Serializable 
{

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "lecture_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private int lecture;

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @OneToOne
    private int student;

    private int year;
}
```

Student

```
@Entity
@Table(name="STUDENT")
@Data
@NamedQuery(name = "Student.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM Student s")
public class Student
{
    private static final long           serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID", nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)    
    private int id;

    @Column(name="FIRSTNAME", nullable=false)
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name="LASTNAME", nullable=false)
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name="YEAR_OF_BIRTH")
    private int yearOfBirth;

    @Column(name="GENDER")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender gender;        
}
```

Lecture (Using Lecturer)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="LECTURE")
public class Lecture
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)  
    private int id;

    @Column(name="TITLE")
    private String title;

    @JoinColumn(name="LECTURER_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Lecturer lecturer;

    @Column(name = "ROOM")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Room room;

    @Column(name = "DAY_OF_WEEK")
    private DayOfWeek dow;

    @JoinColumn(name = "PREREQUISITE_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Lecture prerequisite;             

}
```

When i try to build a query i get way to many results. (SQL Server prints 129 on the same query, JPA 90k+)

The Query:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT"
            + "  l.title, l.dow, l.room "
            + ", t.name, CASE WHEN (t.nobel_price_year != NULL) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'No' END"
            + ", e.year, e.exam_taken, e.exam_passed "
            + ", CONCAT(s.lastname,', ', s.firstname) AS student "
            + "FROM Lecture l "
            + "JOIN Lecturer t "
            + "JOIN Enrollment e "
            + "JOIN Student s "
            + "ORDER BY l.id", EmpireDBExample.class);
```

The Code is generated by hand since SQL Server connection isnt applicable to Eclipse (as far as i know / found out).

Is there an Error in the Mappings?
Do i need to add Join Conditions? If so, how can i achieve this? The "ON a.id = b.id" does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since  `ON ...` isn't working (Hibernate 5 would support it) you need to join along a path or use where conditions to filter rows that don't fit. Currently you're cross joining all lectures, lecturers, enrollments and students, even if they aren't related.

Another problem would be that there's no code path from `Lecture` to `Enrollment` so you might want to start with the `Enrollment` instead. Thus the query could look like this (I'll skip the common parts):

```
... FROM Enrollment e  
      JOIN e.lecture l  //join the lecture for the enrollment
      JOIN l.lecturer t //join the lecturer for the lecture
      JOIN e.student s  //join the enrolled student
```

One final recommentdation: "I have four tables describing the Database" - change your thinking here. You have four *entities* describing your model and those are *mapped* to the database (that mapping could change though). Thus when dealing with JPA queries you need to think in terms of entities and not tables, e.g. since there's no path from `Lecture` to `Enrollment` and unless your JPA provider supports generic `ON` you need to find an entry point and a path to everything you want to join (e.g. there's a path from `Enrollment` to `Lecture` so you start with `Enrollment`).